# Implement a Chat application without a DB

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, servlets, chat

A chat application can be implemented using a database (browser send a request conterminously with a particular period  and get data from a table which keeps messages).

I want to know that, is there a way to implement a chat application using Ajax and jsp/servlets in HTTP and no database connection ? I know jsp,servlets. How can session,request,responses be handled internally in a jsp/servlet application ?

Comment: database isn't really a requirement for a chat. Read about comet (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming) ) and node.js (http://nodejs.org/)

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't want to use a database?

Comment: https://github.com/jmg/node-simple-chat/blob/master/chat.js

Comment: Thanks. Would u explain little bit about chat.js?

Comment: Chat.js in this case is just a simple random example to illustrate the principle -- node.js/asp/jsp/etc backend responding to polls with global/shared/static array/list/queue/stack of messages, popping/dequeuing/shifting them occasionally to keep memory footprint down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the non-production, educational version you can use Application Scope:

You can have an application scoped variable holding the chat list

E.g. use [`<jsp:useBean scope="application">`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/11/syntaxref11.fm14.html) (one instance per application)

And as long as you have thread safety goggles, and you synchronize where needed, you are fine

But as mentioned, try to check **node.js**, it seems like the natural candidate for that

**Edit:**

Note that the application context is per VM, e.g. not the most scaling approach

You can use also [`ServletContext.setAttribute`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) (same syncronization and scaling issues)

Comment: Thank you very much. What will happen if there are more users chatting ? won't it be a load to the container ?

Comment: This is by far not a production solution, more of a starting point, but the load will be on the syncronization of the read/writes, so if you use the right data structure, theoretically, this can support many users up to some point, the issue comes when you need to scale out (add more nodes) then you need to synchronize cache / memory etc. Try to look at some NoSQL DBs (MongoDB?) they tend to scale a bit better in most cases

Answer (score 1):

A database is just a glorified file. If your data is simple enough and you don't want to deal with databases just write to a file?

Comment: Thanks. Writing to a file is something `IO`.I m looking a way which not keep data in a db table or a file, but in something like sessions/sessionscops .

Comment: Sessions are stored in files! (by default)

Answer (score 1):

If you are a java guy, what you need seems to me like a good fit with [spire.io](http://spire.io), a service that allows you to build server-less, database-less applications with a java client.